# Vue 3 Leave animation is not working. Transition issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, transition

I have an issue regarding leaving animation. It works on enter correctly.
Parent component:

```
    <transition name="openedBar">
      <nav-bar v-if="burgerIsOpened" @close="toggleBurger"></nav-bar>
    </transition>
```

NavBar component:

```
<template>
<div class="container--mobile" @click="tryClose">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/auth">Войти в личный кабинет</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/cart">Корзина</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/catalogue">Каталог</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/cactus">Доставка</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/cactus">Программа скидок</router-link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <router-link to="/cactus">О нас</router-link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Styles for parent component:

```
.openedBar-enter-active {
  // transition: all 1.1s ease;
  animation: modal 1.1s ease-out;
}
.openedBar-leave-active {
  animation: modal 1.1s ease-in reverse;
}

@keyframes modal {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50px) scale(0.9);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  }
}
```

It doesn't matter how much time I'll set for leaving animation, it doesn't work anyway. As soon as I close the burger-menu, it just disappears.
Maybe my explanations are a bit strange, cause I'm just a newbee, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

If memory serves me right, v-if will remove the element from the DOM when false and since it is removed it cannot animate. Maybe you can try with v-show?

Comment: Yes, It doesn't help also. You were right that v-if removes an element from the DOM, however before removal of the element transition in vue.js checks whether this element must be animated for leaving. It animates it and only after animation the element is removed. I've looked through documentation regarding my issue and didn't find out a solution.

Comment: I had the same issue in a recent Vue 3 project. I couldn't make it work so I switched to v-show and indeed it works, since the element remains in the DOM.
Nevertheless, I had an exactly similar case in Vue 2 and it was working fine with v-if. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

the animation is working,the problem is in your template

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="burgerIsOpened = !burgerIsOpened">Toggle</button>
    <transition name="openedBar">
      <div
        class="container--mobile"
        @click="burgerIsOpened = false"
        v-if="burgerIsOpened"
      >
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/auth">Войти в личный кабинет</router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/cart">Корзина</router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/catalogue">Каталог</router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/cactus">Доставка</router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/cactus">Программа скидок</router-link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <router-link to="/cactus">О нас</router-link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


export default {
  data: () => {
    return {
      burgerIsOpened: false,
    };
  },
  name: 'App',

};
</script>

<style>
.openedBar-enter-active {
  // transition: all 1.1s ease;
  animation: modal 1.1s ease-out;
}
.openedBar-leave-active {
  animation: modal 1.1s ease-in reverse;
}

@keyframes modal {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50px) scale(0.9);
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0) scale(1);
  }
}
</style>
```